# How to prevent saving of referred entity when using @IdClass?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have two entities, `Type` and `TypeValue`. Each `Type` can have several `TypeValue`s. While trying to persist a new `TypeValue`, I get a database error that `Type` already exists (which is correct, but I don't want to add it again, I want to add just a new 'TypeValue'). I have similar classes without `IdClass` that are working, so I assume that either the @IdClass definition is wrong or I forgot to define something so that the referred object is not updated.

How to prevent saving of the referred entity `Type` when using `@IdClass` for `TypeValue`?

Class definitions:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TYPE", schema = "VOC")
public class Type implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "TYPEID")
  private String typeID;

  @Column(name = "NAME")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "type")
  private List<TypeValue> listTypeValue;

  // constructor, getter, setter, equals, hashcode, ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(TypeValueID.class)
@Table(name = "TYPE_VALUE", schema = "VOC")
public class TypeValue implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "TYPEID")
  @ForeignKey(name = "TYPEVALUE_FK")
  private Type type;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "VALUE")
  private String value;

  // constructor, getter, setter, equals, hashcode, ...
}

public class TypeValueID implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  String type;
  String value;

  // equals, hashcode
}
```

Example of usage:

```
Type type = ... // get existing type with typeID "DETAIL"

Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
TypeValue newTypeValue = new TypeValue(type, "new value");
session.save(newTypeValue);
session.flush();
```

Thrown exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "type_pkey"
  Detail: Key (typeid)=(DETAIL) already exists.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
       ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `type` attribute in the `TypeValueID` class is wrong, the class should look like this:

```
public class TypeValueID implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  Type type;
  String value;

  // equals, hashcode
}
```

The [JPA Persistence API 2.1 documentation](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) states:

> The names of the fields or properties in the primary key class and the
>   primary key fields or properties of the entity must correspond and
>   their types must match according to the rules specified in Section
>   2.4, “Primary Keys and Entity Identity” and Section 2.4.1, “Primary Keys Corresponding to Derived Identities”.

And the rule that applies in this case is:

> If the composite primary key class is represented as an id class, the
>   names of primary key fields or properties in the primary key class and
>   those of the entity class to which the id class is mapped must
>   correspond and their types must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

please change your **String typeID** to int or long. Then use @GeneratedValue for auto-increment.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private int typeID ;
```

Check this example

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private int uID ;

private String uName ;
private String uEmail ;
private String uPassword;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Reminder> uReminders = new ArrayList<>();
```

Next Entity

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class Reminder {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private int reminderID ;

private Date reminderDate ;
private String reminderDescription ;
```

Comment: I'm (currently) not allowed to use surrogate keys, so I'm stuck with natural keys, which is in this case a string. But otherwise this would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the foreign key column with @Id.

```
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "TYPEID")
  @ForeignKey(name = "TYPEVALUE_FK")
  private Type type;
```

So it is expecting unique value in the column "type".Hope this may help.

Comment: I know, but it is a composed key of Type and TypeValue, so the combination should be unique. Also, I have similar classes (using composed keys and referring to one another) without IdClass annotation that are working.